# package structure is changed in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, configuration

I have a dynamic web project which is perfectly working . Then i tried to change it to mvn web project using `mvn eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=2.0` command then my package structure is changed . `main.java` packages added to my package . I tried to change in .classpath file by adding

```
<classpathentry kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src/main/java">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="optional" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry excluding="**" kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src/main/resources">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
```

but project package is not changing.
Below is my changed project structure . How can i bring it back to normal(remove main.java from package)
Thanks in advance

[image]

EDIT:

when i tried to edit source folder it is showing following error:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the source folders in your project configuration under Java build path

[image]